# Does creating a new branch in git create a new folder

Tags: git

I need multiple folders with the entire site sitting in it.

```
DEV/Local
LIVE
```

So I already have my `Dev/Hub` branch and when I push into my `Hub` branch it auto pushes to live. This is dangeous as now any local changes I make goes straight to live.

So I would like to have a middle ground, `Stage`

The simple way i believe to do this is create another branch, which will let me put all my sites folders in there. Then on the server just create a sub domain and have everything in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New branch in Git does **not** create new folder: this is logical change in metadata, not in physical representation